# Posting multiple values to a single field in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, serialization

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to post multiple value types to a single field in my serializer class. For example, I want to post values for "Temp (C)", "Humidity(%)", "Pyra(WPM)" all under the "value" field.

I'm using extra_kwargs in my serializer class to tell my "value" field to accept the different value types I post to it. However, when I try to post using Postman, only the value for the first matching field ("Temp (C)" in this case) will get posted, not all the others. I was wondering if there was a way to have all the field types posted so I don't have to make a new post request for every value type I need?

I know I could hardcode these value names into my models.py and serializer.py, but I need to keep models.py how it is right now.

Also, here is an example of the JSON I'm trying to post:

{"Node ID": "2", "Temp (C)": "22.6", "Humidity(%)": "29.67", "Pyra (WPM)": "118.9", "System Time": "1592287220"}

This is the response I get:

{
"id": 80,
"System Time": 1592287220.0,
"Node ID": "2",
"Temp (C)": 22.6,
"units": null,
"valueName": null
}

**models.py**

```
class DataValueTable(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.FloatField()
    sensorName = models.TextField(null=True)
    valueName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
    units = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class DataValueTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataValueTable
        fields = ['id', 'System Time', 'Node ID', 'Temp (C)', 'units', 'valueName']
        extra_kwargs = {
            "Node ID": {"source": "sensorName"},
            "System Time": {"source": "timestamp"},
            "Temp (C)": {"source": "value"},
            "Humidity(%)": {"source": "value"},
            "Pyra(WPM)": {"source": "value"},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return DataValueTable.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.timestamp = validated_data.get('timestamp', instance.timestamp)
        instance.sensorName = validated_data.get('sensorName', instance.sensorName)
        instance.valueName = validated_data.get('valueName', instance.valueName)
        instance.value = validated_data.get('value', instance.value)
        instance.units = validated_data.get('units', instance.units)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class DataValueTableList(APIView):

    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        info = DataValueTable.objects.all()
        serializer = DataValueTableSerializer(info, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = DataValueTableSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: If you need to store a variety of values in the same field there are a couple ways to do it, in terms of DB design. One is to have a field that can support a list of values (`ArrayField` in Django, I believe) or you can abstract that field to it's own table and relate it back to the one it's currently on. With your current design, you will need to have multiple entries in the table, each with the unique information for the `value` field, as that field only accepts a single value per entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else struggling with posting multiple values look into the **bulk_create** Django method to post multiple lines of data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create.

Bulk_create isn't exactly what I was originally trying to do but it is the best solution I have come across. It also significantly increases posting speed which is a huge plus.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you problem you want to save a instance of `DataValueTable` for each item of `extra_kwargs`, you can do something like this:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        for key in self.extra_kwargs.keys():
            data_value = validated_data.get(key)
            if data_value:
                DataValueTable.objects.create(valueName=key, value=data_value, **validated_data)
```

Comment: Yes! I think this is what I'm trying to do. I tried your code and it didn't seem to change anything but it looks just like what I'm trying to do. I may just need to play around with it. The extra_kwargs is only defined in the meta class so I had to put your def create in the meta class as well. Do you think that's why it didn't change anything?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the `create` method outside the meta class, you need to find a way of get the `extra_kwargs` insede the `create` method